# Toggling individual toggle switches within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I have unique id's for toggles being built dynamically within table rows and I got the css appropriately grabbing them using [attr*="checkbox"]; however, no matter which toggle I click only the top one toggles. I have 0 JS right now and I have no idea where to start with getting individual ones to toggle, since they're dynamically generated. I found how to set the attributes to true and false. But everything I have found online isn't straight forward.

```html
 <table class="table table-hover table-md ">

    <thead>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left tableHead">RoleId</td>
        <td class="text-left tableHead">Role</td>
        <td class="text-right tableHead">Delete</td>
          </tr>
    </thead>
           @*--Table Body For Each to pull DB records--*@
              <tbody>
                @{int i = 0;}
                @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
                 {                                   
                  <tr>                                
                    <td>@role.RoleID</td>
                    <td>@role.RoleName</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox@(i)" class="ios-toggle"/>
                    <label for="checkbox@(i)" class="checkbox-label float-right"></label>
                    </td>

                  </tr>                                       
                  i++;
                 }
               </tbody>
 </table>
```

css:

```css
.ios-toggle, .ios-toggle:active {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5000px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .checkbox-label:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-indent: 40px;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        /* right: auto; */
        background: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
    }

    .checkbox-label:after {
        content: attr(data-off);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: -300px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #bfbfbf;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

.ios-toggle:checked + .checkbox-label {
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px rgba(19,191,17,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px rgba(19,191,17,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px rgba(19,191,17,1);
}

    .ios-toggle:checked + .checkbox-label:before {
        left: calc(100% - 36px);
        /*box-shadow*/
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px transparent,0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px transparent,0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px transparent,0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

/* GREEN CHECKBOX */

[id*="checkbox"] + .checkbox-label {
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px rgba(19,191,17,1),0 0 0 2px #dddddd;
}

[id*="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox-label {
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1),0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1),0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1),0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 154, 68, 1);
}

    [id*="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox-label:after {
        color: #009A44 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the data from your model, I was able to make a makeshift table with your code. I changed your selector in your `.css` code from `[id^="checkbox"]` to `"input:checkbox[id^='checkbox']"`. This will select your check boxes where their id's start with `checkbox` since it seems they all will. This also seems to select each individual checkbox as well. Hopefully this is a push in the right direction for you.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kz1e5fd/

Comment: It is giving me a "Expected a selector for the style rule" warning and it's not working in my code. Even though it is in the JSFiddle :(

Comment: @S.Kellar I've updated my css code within my jsfiddle. Try it out now and see what you get. The .css was complaining that it didn't start with something like a class or div selector. But I think I've fixed it, so try it out now and see if you get the same error.

Comment: it's still only toggling the top one no matter what I click on.. how weird.

Comment: hmm, try it in incognito mode. Maybe you have some cookie set or something. And did you get any new errors?

Comment: no dice on the incognito. No errors, the css classes aren't being applied. I just noticed the green is the default green and not the one I set with ```.checkbox-label > [id^="checkbox"]:checked```

Comment: Do you have a link tag to your css file in your html? It should look something like `<link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Comment: Yeah, when I did my original classes I posted it changed the color; however, it'd still only toggle the top one. In this case, the colors are defaulted but they're still all sized correctly. So those bottom 3 classes are not applying.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem you're talking about. Everything I'm doing, I can click the individual buttons. Does my jsfiddle work when you try it out? If so, then the problem lies within your data somewhere if I had to take a guess.